# can't get es6 react to bind event

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm migrating a react app to ES6 and moving events so they're bound in the constructor, here's a very basic example:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';

export default class Button extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.click = this.click.bind(this);
    }
    click() {
        alert('hi');
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <button onClick={this.click}>click</button>
        );
    }
}

if(typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    ReactDom.render(<Button/>, document.getElementById('button-spot'));
}
```

The button renders correctly, and there aren't any server/client errors, but when I click this button, nothing happens. I also tried `console.log()` and its not logging. Am I doing the `event.bind(this)` binding wrong?

more context:

my index.js router:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', { 
        button: ReactDom.renderToString(<Button/>)
    });
});
```

html page:

```
<div id='button-spot'><%-button%></div>
```

---

**EDIT**

---

I tried Andre's suggestion below

```
onClick={x => alert(1)}
```

and the event isn't firing, what could the issue be?

Comment: have u tried place the function inline there to check if the event is being triggered? like: `onClick={x => alert(1)}`

Comment: @AndréJunges no but I can try!

Comment: @AndréJunges its not being triggered

Comment: with an ES2015 class your methods are already bound to `this`, so that line shouldn't be required at all.

Comment: @NathanCox the click event is being bound, not the method

Comment: It still shouldn't be required. React has already handled event binding for you via the `onClick` attribute. The only thing you should need to pass to it is the method itself, which you've already done via `onClick={this.click}`. I've never had React require me to manually bind events for any component.

Comment: @NathanCox so why does every tutorial say to do it?

Comment: As far as I know, binding is only required if you're actually using `this` inside of the method itself to reference the component class (which would be normally), but in this example you aren't. The point I'm trying to make is that binding `this` to it doesn't seem to be your problem, the actual event propagation would be. Especially if `onClick={() => alert('hi')}` isn't working for you (which would also bind the component scope to the method).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, when using DOM event handlers, you can't render React only from the server. You either need to render both client/server React code or use a server-side rendering solution that addresses that problem directly.

Here are a few good starting points:

- [Good answers to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36233309/react-js-serverside-rendering-and-event-handlers)
- [Example of server side rendering with event handling](https://github.com/mhart/react-server-example)

Comment: that's why I have `if(typeof window !== 'undefined') {...` This already works in regular javascript but not ES6, has nothing to do with server side rendering

Comment: Interesting. Have you tried  `this.click = () => this.click();` in the constructor?

Comment: didn't work... there's something weird going on, events aren't being triggered

Comment: Are they not being triggered in any component, or just this one?

Comment: Then it seems like the it is a server side rendering issue. Because if no events are being triggered that means these components are being rendered as strings from the server side. If you wrote that code client side that should work.

Comment: yes, more likely what @garrettmaring mentioned above.

Comment: oh I see.. my web pack build wasn't including my classes from the server-side.