# React Draft.js server side rendering

Tags: javascript, express, reactjs, draftjs

I would like to use *Draft.js* with React and server rendering. Problem is, component is't rendered whole. So, in *object inspector* I can see div elements, but page is empty, without any text input or the other.

This is my component code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Editor, EditorState} from 'draft-js';

export class RichText extends React.Component {
  constructor() {    
    super();
    this.state = {editorState: EditorState.createEmpty()};
    this.onChange = (editorState) => this.setState({editorState});
  }
  render() {
    return React.createElement(Editor, {
      editorState: this.state.editorState,
      onChange: this.onChange
    });        
  }
}
```

And server test file:

```
var express = require("express");
import * as path from "path";

var React = require('react');
var ReactDOMServer = require('react-dom/server');

import {RichText} from "../src/components/richtext/api/richtext-api";

var app = express();

//register view engine
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, "./views"));
app.set('view engine', 'vash');

app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {  

  var richTexteditor = new RichText();

  var component = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(richTexteditor.render());

  res.render('index', {component: component});
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "./wwwroot")));

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Can you help me, where is problem? 
Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36233309/react-js-serverside-rendering-and-event-handlers

Comment: Ok, so I have to  do ReactDOM render on client side by rendered component reactid. I understand it well?

Comment: basically right, but not regular `render`, just attach the server-side rendered html and JS event handlers.