# How to render components when componet tags are in a string?

Tags: reactjs

I am getting on string from a rest API containing component tags. 
Following is example string:-

```
let stringFromAPI = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <TooltipComponent>consectetur</TooltipComponent> adipiscing elit. Non enim, <ButtonComponent>si omnia</ButtonComponent> non sequebatur, idcirco non erat ortus illinc. Re mihi non aeque satisfacit, et quidem locis pluribus. Ita relinquet duas, de quibus etiam atque etiam consideret. Ad <TooltipComponent>corpus</TooltipComponent> diceres pertinere-, sed ea, quae dixi, ad corpusne refers?"
```

When I am rendering it components are displayed as text instead of rendering.
How can i make components in string rendered?

```
    render() {
        return ( <div>{stringFromAPI}</div>
    )
}
```

dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: rawMarkup}} renders only html elements not react components.

Comment: so the tags in this example are: **consectetur**, **si omnia**, and **corpus**? Maybe if you prepared a jsfiddle it will be easier to fix your problem

Comment: Question edited please look it now.

Comment: This in not duplicate I am trying to render component not html with reactjs

Comment: You could loop through the string that you get from the server and whenever you find a `'<'` you track that index and similarly you track the index of `'>'`. You could have a function doing that for you where it will return a list of objects or list of lists that has an object or list for each component with start and end index. Then you would slice the string by start and end multiple times to get components out and render them separate from your raw html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have access to backend source code. In this case, you will need to render React components to string first then concatenate and append them to the DOM in front-end.

Use `ReactDOMServer.renderToString` to translate React component into string.

This [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hhtvb2nL/) may give you an idea.

Comment: Hi Ming, My static components are getting replace well. But I want to use material-ui components. material-ui 's compnent's events are not working.

Comment: @TOM,  `renderToString` only generate HTML, event binding needs JS's help. Check out this great answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36234985/2021245. You may need to modify your architecture a little bit for event-binding to happen.

Comment: It would be great help if you can share any example for event binding that can help me.

Comment: @TOM, The `ReactDOM.render` is the only (easy) method of attaching event handlers for React Component. https://jsfiddle.net/0kompn2d/1/. This JSFiddle is an example showing only passing a string is not enough. Therefore, if you want event binding, you have to let front-end execute the component code and render it to DOM using `ReactDOM.render`. Actually, you may be interested in a term called "isomorphic app". It is a big topic, you can find plenty of examples online.