# JavaScript function calls are not working inside table dropdown when ReactDOMServer and innerHTML are used

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, innerhtml, react-dom-server

JavaScript functions calls are not working inside the table dropdown which is added to the DOM by innerHTML

```
  employeesRetrieval = e => {

    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/employeesRetrieval')
      .then( res => {

        let totalActiveEmployees = res.data[0];

        let activeEmployeesAdder = ``;

          totalActiveEmployees.forEach( ele => {

            let role = '';
            if(ele.empRole === 0){
              role = 'Admin';
            }else{
              role = 'Employee';
            }
            activeEmployeesAdder += ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
                                    <tr>
                                      <td>{ele.empId}</td>
                                      <td>{ele.empName}</td>
                                      <td>{ele.empEmail}</td>
                                      <td>{role}</td>
                                      <td className = "editColumn">

                                        <div className="btn-group">
                                          <button className="noCaret" data-toggle="dropdown" title = "Edit">
                                            <MoreVertical className = "editIcon" id = "editIcon"/>
                                          </button>
                                          <ul className="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                            <li className = "dropdown-item" role = "button" name = {ele.empId} onSelect = {() => this.showEmployeeUpdateModal('active', ele.empId)}>Edit details</li>
                                            <li className = "dropdown-item" role = "button" name = {ele.empId} onSelect = {() => this.directEmployeeStatusChange('inactive', ele.empId)}>Make inactive</li>
                                          </ul>
                                        </div>

                                      </td>
                                    </tr>
                                  );
          });
          document.getElementById('activeEmployeesLoader').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('activeEmployeesTableContent').innerHTML = activeEmployeesAdder;
```

[image: Table]

After opening the dropdown:

[image: Table with dropdown opened]

No response or error is coming after clicking them. I tried changing everything like onClick attributes and changing *ul* and *li* to *select* and *option* tags. Nothing seems to work for me.

The two functions :

```
showEmployeeUpdateModal = (e, id) => {
      console.log('INSIDE THE FUNCTION');
      /*
         SOME LOGIC
      */
    };
```

```
directEmployeeStatusChange = (e, id) => {
      console.log('INSIDE THE FUNCTION');
      /*
         SOME LOGIC
      */
    };
```

Comment: on selecting any **li** i added the function call to these functions, scroll to the right to see those calls

Answer (score 1):

You are using `ReactDOMServer.renderToString` on that chunk of code that includes your event listeners.

As the name suggests, `renderToString` gives you plain HTML, so the event handlers won't work as written.

Have a look at a similar question [React.js Serverside rendering and Event Handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36233309/react-js-serverside-rendering-and-event-handlers)