# How do I make React app as server side using express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-18

I am trying React18 + express to make my react as server rendered application.

I have created a very simple express server that is supposed to send an `HTML` code to the browser.

```
import express from "express"
import React from "react"
import { renderToPipeableStream } from "react-dom/server"

const app = express()

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  const { pipe } = renderToPipeableStream(<h1>Hello World</h1>, {
    onShellReady() {
      res.setHeader("content-type", "text/html")
      pipe(res)
    },
  })
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("RUNNING..")
})
```

The `Hello World` doesn't get printed and i am stuck with this error -

```
const { pipe } = renderToPipeableStream(<h1>Hello World</h1>, {
                                          ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
    at Loader.moduleStrategy (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:147:18)
    at async link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:64:21)
```

However, when i send a plain string as "Hello World" it does rendered on the browser at the given PORT.

Why it cannot send a simple `h1` tag as an HTML?

Comment: Because `<h1>` is only understood within the context of `document` and node doesn't understand what that is. You'll likely have to transpile any JSX using Babel, or [just use `React.createElement`](https://remarkablemark.medium.com/server-side-rendering-with-react-46715f501651) instead.

Comment: @Andy but this is not JSX, rather a simple h1 tag?

Comment: Then why is it not quoted? I think you are mixing JSX with Javascript and HTML.

Comment: @GrzegorzW well why it would be quoted? If i do like this "<h1>hello world</h1>", the h1 tag gets rendered as well (obviously). I do not understand, what transpilation do i need for an HTML h1 tag?

Comment: There is not such thing as "h1 tag" in Javascript. And you are trying to run a Javascript code. So either this has to be a string or you have to run a pre-processing on the file (aka transpilation) so that you get an output that is a valid javascript.
I think if you would share your project/folder structure and a command you try to run this with it would be easier to explain or confirm.

Comment: @GrzegorzW Oh right! I created a minimal repo here - https://github.com/abhinav-anshul/react18-server
 The goal here is to create a react18 app and bundle it using parcel. then make it server side rendered using express by opening a port on 3000.
Very thanks :)