# Clip-path works in css, but doesn't work in JS (safari problem)

Tags: javascript, css, webkit, clip-path

I used `clip-path` property to clip picture, and I did this:

**CSS:**

```
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(40% 100%, 100% 100%, 100%  10%); 
 clip-path: polygon(40% 100%, 100% 100%, 100%  10%);
```

**JS:**

```
x.style.WebkitClipPath = 'polygon(0% 100%,  0 0, 80% 0)';
x.style.clipPath = 'polygon(0% 100%,  0 0, 80% 0)';
```

Result is that, transition and CSS propery works in chrome, firefox, opera.
But for safari, it works only CSS file, transition `onmouseover` doesn't work.

I wouldn't ask If I have to, I spent 2-3 days to find a solution. Tnx in advance people.

Comment: This? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41860477/why-doesnt-css-clip-path-with-svg-work-in-safari

Comment: I will try that and tnx, but is it work with transition property? I want to change shape onmouseover.