# SVG <Image> tag only partially rendering on iPhone

Tags: html, ios, svg, rendering

I have been developing a web page "game" on my PC based in HTML, SVG, and Javascript.  It has a large image of the earth loaded into the SVG views through the SVG <image> tag.  Testing on my PC this works with no problem, however recently I published it to a public web page (http://rbarryyoung.com/EarthOrbitalSimulator.html) and discovered that only the bottom right quarter of the SVG is rendering on both SVG views on my iPhone and iPad.  Like this: [image]

At first, I thought that it was just the image in the SVG viewports, but then I realized that the entire SVG viewport was black except for the lower-right quadrant.  The SVG viewport is correctly fully sized, it just appears as if there is some black mask over 3/4s of it (or only 1/4 of it renders).

Here's what I think are the relevant HTML code lines, the containing Div tag for the first SVG view (line 67):

```
<div id="divSvg1" 
    style="position:relative; z-index:1; margin:15px; 
        top:100px; 
        width:640px; height:640px; 
        background-color:black;
        float:left;"
    >
```

The SVG tag (line 104):

```
    <svg  id="svgEa" 
        style="width:100%; height:100%;"
        viewBox="-7500 -7500 15000 15000"
        preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
        clip-path="url(#svgEaClip)"
        transform="scale(1.0,1.0)"
        version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <!-- NOTE: All internal units are in KM (or %)  -->
```

And the embedded Image tag (starting at line 160):

```
        <g id="gEaAll" transform="scale(1.0,1.0)" >

            <!-- ... -->

            <g id="gEaSurfaceFacingBottom" class="eaSurfaceFacing">
                <g id=gEarthImage>
                    <!-- ...  -->
                    <image x="-6413" y="-6413" width="12826" height="12826" href="eosImages/globe-arctic 8bit.png" />
                </g>
            </g>
```

The second SVG view is a shadowed (<use..> tag), zoomed view of the first with the same problem.

I have tested this on my PC, on both screens in Chrome, Edge, and IE, where it works correctly on all of them.  I have also tested this on my iPhone with both Safari and Edge and my iPad with Safari, Chrome, and Edge with the same failure on all of them.  I have tried just a bare <img> tag of the PNG file outside of SVG and that works fine on these platforms.

I do not have any Android platforms to test with, so if anyone wants to try it and let me know, I can add those results here.

I have researched this, and though there's a bunch of stuff about iOS not rendering images, mostly those are a complete failure to render, rather than this very specific partial rendering, and much less specific stuff about SVG differences.  Ultimately I didn't find anything that seemed to be the same problem.

To summarize then, my question is:  what is causing this problem or what have I done wrong, and how can I fix it?  (I do understand that I will need to have a different style/CSS layout for mobile, but I still need to know what needs to be changed to make this render correctly)

Comment: At your Page, line 114 and 301 `<clipPath id="svgEaClip"><rect width="100%" height="100%" /></clipPath>`. What does this particular line do. If i delete following `<cliPath>` it's rendering. And there is no problem with your `<image />` tag.

Comment: Works perfectly on android. Seems to be Safari issue

Comment: @Fussionweb That is a clipPath to prevent elements of the SVG viewport that are outside of the viewbox from showing on the web page.  One of the browsers that I tested on Windows was doing this.  That is, there were large elements that were partially outside of the viewport, so they should have been implicitly clipped, but they weren't.  So I added this clipPath to explicitly clip all elements to only be visible within the viewport.

Comment: Just get into the Developer tool, and check the clip-path is out of your Content. Your clip-path too working fine, it just showing the Content on its path, Just try to fix the x and y for the clip.

Comment: Check this link might help you [clipPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath). it doesn't have an issue in Safari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add X and Y coordinates for your `<rect />`. In your case, your Clip-Path Rectangle is not in an exact coordinate.

Here is the code working for me

```html
    <clipPath>
         <rect x="-7500px" y="-7500px" width="100%" height="100%" />
    <cliPath>
```

replace this code with your `<clipPath>` on line 114 and 301.

Here is the Screenshot
[image]

Moreover here is a live demo that worked on my Mac Safari as well in windows Chrome, where I took one part of your code.

[image: Edit nervous-sanderson-qxnin]

Comment: Should I really us the "px" on the X and Y attributes?  Isn't the scale of anything within the /<svg/> element just the viewbox coordinate system and therefore unitless?

Comment: Yep, that did it!  FYI, it does work without the "px".  Thx

Answer (score 0):

### Update

Check the answer by @fussionweb.

Orignal answer:
You can try the `-webkit-` prefix before `clip-path`. It seems to be a safari issue related to clip-path.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41860477/why-doesnt-css-clip-path-with-svg-work-in-safari is specifically dealing with this issue.

Comment: @it happens with both Chrome and Edge on iOS also.  But I will try this.

Comment: Hmm, my webpage is using SVG attribute to clip SVG, but the link you provided is using CSS, and I think that "-webkit-" is specifically CSS isn't it?  Does an `-webkit-clip-path` attribute even exist?

Comment: Huh, I just noticed that the Mozilla doc on the clip-path attribute has ***no*** compatibility information filled in.  That seems pretty odd, don't know if I ever saw that before.  (I also didn't realize that I had to explicitly check the compatibility of every single tag attribute that I am using >:(.