# Compile user HTML in browser and display results with React

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I'm working on a piece of my Next.js app, and I'd love to create a section that allows for users to write simple HTML and CSS and compiles the results, displaying them in browser. [Similar to the editor pages on W3](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_editors).

I don't have much to go on in terms of what I've tried, as this is a completely new concept for me, but from the little I've seen in other similar tools, you can compile the code into a `Blob()` and then set that `Blob()` as the `src` for a `iframe`.

How to create an in-browser HTML compiler like this, preferably easily compatible with React/Next.js?

Comment: If you want to compile HTML/CSS/Javascript simply, you can easily create an iframe with "srcdoc" attribute with your desired content directly.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish that using an `iframe` and `textarea`.
`textarea` will be used as an editor and `iframe` as a sandbox to see the result.

```js
const Sandbox = () => {
  const textareaRef = useRef(null);
  const [code, setCode] = useState("");

  const runCode = () => setCode(textAreaRef.current.value);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <textarea ref={textareaRef}></textarea>
        <button onClick={runCode}>Run</button>
      </div>
      <iframe
        src={"data:text/html," + encodeURIComponent(code)}
        title="sandbox"
      />
    </div>
  );
  
}
```

here we create a `ref` to access to `textarea` content, and a button to run user's entered snippet. then pass that code to an `iframe` using `src` attribute and after that it will render the entered code like an existing HTMl page. look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52873226/11320591) for more info on how it works.

see the working example on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-cohen-98thik?file=/src/App.js:0-528)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `ref` attribute to get content from a textarea. To render the content you can define the `srcdoc` of an `iframe` with respective content.

Since you are asking for a place to start, here is a simple tutorial that creates an html/css/js editor with react: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wcVxX7lu2d4

Also I found this article useful: https://medium.com/@nishantsaxena269/html-editor-using-react-98e6ab2183a5

Answer (score -1):

If you want to render html input in react you can do that with this below

```
const App = () => {
  const data = 'lorem <b>ipsum</b>';

  return (
    <div
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: data}}
    />
  );
}

export default App;
```

This will render any html you type.